# Commit only stage/index, ignoring conflicts

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick, git-merge-conflict

I have a huge commit, which I cherry-picked. The pick now creates a sum of conflicts (in working-tree).
Now I would like to commit all the staged (successfully merged) changes without having to resolve all conflicts.

Naively I always thought, commit would only work on the stage, but when I try, I get the message, that I cannot commit without resolving the conflicts.

Can someone explain to me what is going on and how I could fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to resolve the conflicts as conflicts only happen when git cannot automatically merge the branches. They mostly occur when the same line was modified in 2 separate commits.

**Example**

master branch:

```
L1. git
L2. is
L3. awesome
```

branch A and B was branched off from master

Commit x applied on branch A

```
L1. git
L2. is not
L3. awesome
```

Diff

```
 git
-is
+is not
 awesome
```

Commit y applied on branch B

```
L1. git
L2. isn't
L3. awesome
```

Diff

```
 git
-is
+isn't
 awesome
```

When you merge *branch A* and try to merge *branch B* afterwards into master, git cannot decide what to put for L2. Whilst resolving the conflicts you have to make that decision.

**How to resolve the conflicts**

Easiest way to resolve is selecting which version of the file you want to keep.

To select the version of the file that is on the current branch (HEAD)

```
git checkout --ours <filename>
```

To select the version of the file that is on the other branch (the branch that you pulled / cherry-picked from. possibly the remote branch):

```
git checkout --theirs <filename>
```

Or you can edit the files one by one and removing the conflict markers (`<<<<<<<`, `=======`, `>>>>>>>`) and picking which version to use

Afterwards you need to mark them as resolved by doing:

```
git add <filename>
```

Tip: You can use `.` as the filename to select all the files under the current directory.

Comment: Could you explain WHY I have to resolve the conflicts? With huge commits, resolving is unpractical.

Comment: I want to do the same thing without resolving the conflicts :(